# Getting approval comments in trigger

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have an approval process that updates the status on an object.  Then I have a trigger on that object that says if the status is changing to "Approved" then go out and get all the approval steps related to this record.

```
public static map<id,list<ProcessInstance>> getApprovalInfoByObjec(set<id> ObjectsID){
    map<id,list<ProcessInstance>> mapReturn = new map<id,list<ProcessInstance>>();
    list<ProcessInstance> listTemp;
    for(id objectID: ObjectsID){
      for(ProcessInstance PI: [SELECT Id, TargetObjectId,(SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps),(SELECT Id, ActorId, ProcessInstanceId FROM Workitems)
          FROM ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId =: objectID]){

        if(mapReturn.ContainsKey(PI.TargetObjectId)){
          listTemp = mapReturn.get(PI.TargetObjectId);
        }else{
          listTemp = new list<ProcessInstance>();
        }

        listTemp.add(PI);
        mapReturn.put(PI.TargetObjectId,listTemp);
    }
  }
    return mapReturn;
}
```

It works fine for all previous steps. It just doesn't get the latest step and comments.  My fear is that Salesforce is setting the status on my object before it creates the ProcessInstanceStep record for the current step.  Just FYI, I am running this on the after Update trigger on my object.

Comment: Have you tried executing this asynchronously (ie @future) and seeing if you get all approval steps?

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue.  It is the fact that the comments are not committed yet.  I did "fix" it with a @future call.  But it's not the best solution.